# How can I tell bash to properly escape expanded strings?

Tags: bash, escaping

Suppose I have a directory containing the files

```
foo bar.txt  
foo baz.txt
```

(each with a space between 'o' and 'b'). Suppose I would like to do this:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv ${f} `basename ${f} .txt`; done
```

This fails because bash expands `*.txt` to

```
foo bar.txt foo baz.txt
```

instead of

```
foo\ bar.txt foo\ baz.txt
```

i.e. properly escaped as if I had used tab completion.

How can I get bash to properly escape its output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you put quotes in your variables. this way you preserve the space. Also, there's no need to use external command `basename`. the shell can do that for you. (assuming you are using bash)

```
for file in *.txt
do
 mv "$file" "${file%.txt}"
done
```

Comment: ..added the missing terminating quote

Comment: thks. as you are adding it, i am also doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Or if it is one off operation you can use vim:

```
> ls -al
foo bar.txt
foo baz.txt
```

Open vim and execute:

```
:r!ls *.txt
```

This loads files, then execute:

```
:%s/\(\(.*\)\.txt\)/mv "\1" "\2"/gc
```

This will replace the lines with:

```
mv "foo bar.txt" "foo bar"
mv "foo baz.txt" "foo baz"
```

Highlight all with `Ctrl-v` down, then enter `:` and type the rest of this command:

```
:'<,'>!bash
```

That will execute the highlighted commands in bash. Quit vim and check your directory:

```
> ls
foo bar
foo baz
```

Comment: **Or** in `vim` just type: `:!for f in *.txt; do mv "${f}" "${f%.txt}"; done` (assuming Bash is your shell).